# How to use SimpleRandomSample in Apache pig

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, apache-pig

I tried out this script.

```
DEFINE SRS datafu.pig.sampling.SimpleRandomSample('0.01');

examples = LOAD '/home/sreeveni/myfiles/FS/age.txt' as (id,age);
 grouped = GROUP examples BY id;
sampled = FOREACH grouped GENERATE FLATTEN(SRS(examples));
DUMP sampled;
```

What does this implies:

```
SimpleRandomSample('0.01')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
    examples = LOAD '/home/sreeveni/myfiles/FS/age.txt' as (id,age);
    sampled = SAMPLE examples 0.005;
    DUMP sampled;
```

This should generate 0.5% of the number of lines which is around 4. The value you give in the SAMPLE command is a percentage of the total number of lines which is an approximate value. I dont think there is a way to generate a fixed number of lines.

Also if you want to use pig in mapred mode, copy your input file to hdfs using grunt. copyFromLocal /local/source/path /hdfs/path/for/input

Answer (score 4):

Pig is not able to locate the input file.
On the basis of the location given, i guess the data is in your local file system. So run Pig in local mode only.

SimpleRandomSample('0.01') generates data which is 1% of the total population size.
Basically 0.01 is the probability which is multiplied by the data size (p*n) to generate the random sample data.
We use this because we don't have any control on the size of random data produced. But after passing this value, Pig produces sample data roughly of the size of 1% of sample data.

Comment: yes solved :) I was mistakily doing that.What is SimpleRandomSample('0.01') implies

Comment: I supplied a dataset with 796 lines.It outputted the excat same 796 lines as output.why?Are we able to give some value rather than probability.like say if 1 need just 4 lines of data only can we tell that also?